# Как сделать чтобы в дискорд боте музыка проигрывалась без остановки?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, ffmpeg

Вот код, подскажите как сделать чтобы музыка играла бесконечно, пока я ее сам не остановлю.

Напишите что добавить пожалуйста, буду благодарен

```
@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['u', 'ur'])
async def url(ctx, url: str):

    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
            print("Removed old song file")
        await ctx.send("Бот загружает музыку...")
    except PermissionError:
        print("Trying to delete song file, but it's being played")
        await ctx.send("ERROR: Music playing")
        return
    await ctx.send("Почти готово...")
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    ydl_opts = {
        'format' : 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors' : [{ 
            'key' : 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec' : 'mp3',
            'preferredquality' : '192'
            }],
        }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        print("Downloading audio now\n")
        ydl.download([url])

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            name = file
            print(f"Renamed File: {file}\n")
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: print("Song done!")) 
    await ctx.send("Готово!") 
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.09

    nname = name.rsplit("-", 2)
    await ctx.send(f"**Играет трек**: {nname[0]}")
    print("playing\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3", before_options="-stream_loop -1")`

Comment: не помогло(  Куда именно вставить? может я туплю

Comment: все работает, я просто затупил, спасибо!